# android java playing wav audio file from sd card

Tags: java, android, audio, wav, sd-card

I`ve troubles to play a wav audio file from sd card:

This is my code:

```
mp = new MediaPlayer(); //Defined as MediaPlayer above
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(fileNamePath);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The fileNamePath is in this format: /storage/emulated/0/MyApp/name.wav

This is the error code I get:

```
E/MediaPlayer: stop called in state 1, mPlayer(0x0)
E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
```

I hope you can help me here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android media player have some troubles with some wav files, I recommend you to use AudioTrack instead of MediaPlayer.

Here is a example:

```
     new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // just put here your wav file
                File yourWavFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + AUDIO_FOLDER, fileName);
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(yourWavFile);
                int minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(16_000,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
                AudioTrack at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 16_000,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    minBufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

                int i = 0;
                byte[] music = null;
                try {
                        music = new byte[512];
                        at.play();

                        while ((i = fis.read(music)) != -1)
                            at.write(music, 0, i);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    at.stop();
                    at.release();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

Comment: This code gives me a lot of errors, i`m programming in java, how do i call this function correctly? This is the String of the location of my audio file: String file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + AUDIO_FOLDER + "/" + fileName;
How do i use this string? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Florian lol, is a java code(with lamda expression), anyway I edited the response, try the new code :) just replace "yourWavFile" with your File from  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + AUDIO_FOLDER + "/" + fileName

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now i get at the end at.start() an error. It says "invalid method declaration; return type required; Missing method body; or declare abstract". How can I solve this new problem?

Comment: @Florian Oh, just forget to put a brace :) Edited

Comment: Thanks for your help, in general the code works now, but there are coming just strange sounds out, not what the wav file should sound like

Comment: @Florian Right, AudioTrack is a low level programming, so you must configure(sample rate, channel config, audio format etc.) manually =)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, can you maybe tell me how I configure that?